# Split sorted file without cutting blocks

Tags: linux, bash, file, split

I have a large file (20 GB) consisting of 30 million data records. The first field of each record is a *non-unique* key. The file is sorted by this key. I'd like to split this file into chunks, using anything available in a bash shell, such that the chunks are approximately the same size in bytes and all records with the same key go into the same chunk in the same order as in the original file.

I obviously do not want `awk -F";" '{print > $1}' theFile` because I'd prefer on the order of 10 large chunks, not one file per key. Also, `split` alone won't cut it, because I need a way to keep identical keys together.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output. Don't post them as comments or images. Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider splitting according the keys (with your `awk` script, for instance) and then concatenating the result files based on their sizes and on how many chunks you want at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-process the file such that `split` knows where it is allowed to split.

Here, we insert the null byte `\0` to mark that splitting is allowed. Afterwards, we remove all `\0` from the generated files. This assumes that your original data never contains `\0`.

```
awk -F\; '$1!=last {last=$1; if(NR>1) printf "\0"} 1' file > file.tmp
split -t\\0 --filter 'tr -d \\0 > "$FILE"' -n l/10 file.tmp file.
rm file.tmp
```

You can adapt `split`'s options to your liking. Here we split into 10 chunks. Due to our pre-processing and the changed delimiter `-t\\0`, the chunk option `l/…` keeps identical keys together.

To verify that everything worked, you can run

```
for i in file.*; do
  echo "--- $i ---"
  head -n1 "$i"
  echo "[...]"
  tail -n1 "$i"
done
```

I generated a testfile using

```
n=1""000""000; paste -d\; <(shuf -i1-500 -rn$n) <(shuf -rn$n /usr/share/dict/words) | sort -t\; -k1,1n > file
```

and got

```
--- file.aa ---
1;abbesses
[...]
55;Zoroaster
--- file.ab ---
56;abase
[...]
107;zoologists
--- file.ac ---
108;abattoir
[...]
```

and so on.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Much less complicated than the script I was planning to write based on @Dominique's idea.

Comment: Would there have been any harm in leaving out `if(NR>1)`? Seems more cosmetic than urgent. Am I missing something? (This whole idea is beautiful, btw.)

Comment: @PaulHodges Thank you for the compliment. Without `if(NR>1)` the temporary file would start with a `\0`, introducing an empty record into the data. This does not really matter when using `-n l/10` , but if you changed the splitting strategy to `-l 1000` (create a new file every 1000 records) the first file would have only 999 unique keys instead of 1000.

Comment: Yes, but my assumption was that since they didn't want to split one key across files, and the number of keys vary, that the number of records in each file will vary anyway. Did I misread?

Comment: I mean, I'm being pedantic over a nonissue, lol - but it's unlikely that there will be a number of chunks that divide evenly into exactly 1000. This would mean the first group would have 999 and the last would have whatever was left over, with every other being 1000, but I assumed it wouldn't be a problem and stylistically preferred to skip the extra test on each "record". It's so little difference in terms of output *or* total work done that I can't see it as a problem either way. Just trying to make sure I wasn't missing something critical. :)

Comment: You are right. Leaving out the `if(NR>1)` most likely won't matter. I just was pedantic too, trying to make this as correct as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You mention `split` as a tag, but do you know that the UNIX/Linux command `split` exists, especially for this purpose?

The man-page mentions (amongst others):

```
-b, --bytes=SIZE
    put SIZE bytes per output file
```

There are plenty of examples all over the internet.

**Edit: apparently `split` is not a good option**

I've created a file, `try.txt`, with following content:

```
x1 a b
x1 b c
x1 c d
x2 a b
x2 a d
x3 a b
x3 a c
x3 b c
x3 c c
```

First, I need to know how many lines there are per key:

```
Linux prompt>cat try.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
  3 x1
  2 x2
  4 x3
```

(Remark: `uniq -c` shows the **c**ount of **uniq**ue entries)

So, there is 3 times "x1", 2 times "x2", and 4 times "x3". Now let's take those parts:

```
Linux prompt>head -n 3 try.txt
  x1 a b
  x1 b c
  x1 c d

Linux prompt>head -n $((3+2)) try.txt | tail -n 2
  x2 a b
  x2 a d

Linux prompt>head -n $((3+2+4)) try.txt | tail -n 4
  x3 a b
  x3 a c
  x3 b c
  x3 c c
```

It's not an entirely scripted solution, but I guess it might be helpful for you.

Comment: `split` alone won't cut it. You need a way to keep identical keys together.

Comment: @Socowi thanks, perhaps that wasn't clear enough. I've edited my question to include your comment.

Comment: @Sebastian: I've adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Dominique thanks, that is very helpful! Parsing and looping over the  output of uniq -c should be doable.

Comment: @Sebastian I don't understand why you found this helpful, since you said *»I obviously do not want `awk -F";" '{print > $1}' theFile`«*. Isn't this answer basically the same, but with extra-steps?

Comment: Yes, but the extra info in the output of uniq -c is important (I didn't know about uniq). Now I have one line for every set of records with the same key. I can iterate over those lines, output the relevant number of records from the original file, and every n/k lines I switch to e new output file, where n is the number of keys and k the number of chunks. That's a plan at least.